# Regex character sets - and what they contain

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I'm working on a pretty crude sanitizer for string input in Node(express):

I have glanced at some plugins and library, but it seems most of them are either too complex or too heavy. Therefor i decided to write a couple of simple sanitizer-functions on my own.

One of them is this one, for hard-sanitizing most strings (not numbers...)

```
function toSafeString( str ){
    str = str.replace(/[^a-öA-Ö0-9\s]+/g, '');
    return str;
}
```

I'm from Sweden, therefore i Need the åäö letters. And i have noticed that this regex also accept others charachters aswell... for example á or é....

**Question 1)**
Is there some kind of list or similar where i can see WHICH charachters are actually accepted in, say this regex: /[^a-ö]+/g

**Question 2)**
Im working in Node and Express... I'm thinking this simple function is going to stop attacks trough input fields. Am I wrong?

Comment: Don't you wanna include 'ü' & 'é' for handling words like 'Linnéa', 'idé', 'armé' & 'müsli'? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_alphabet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: Find out. :)

```
var accepted = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 65535 /* the unicode BMP */; i++) {
    var s = String.fromCharCode(i);
    if(/[a-ö]+/g.test(s)) accepted.push(s);
}
console.log(s.join(""));
```

outputs

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³
´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö
```

on my system.

---

Question 2: What attacks are you looking to stop? Either way, the answer is "No, probably not".

Instead of mangling user data (I'm sure your, say, French or Japanese customers will have some beef with your validation), make sure to sanitize your data whenever it's going into customer view or out thereof (HTML escaping, SQL parameter escaping, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

`[x-y]` matches characters whose unicode numbers are between that of x and that of y:

```
charsBetween = function(a, b) { 
     var a = a.charCodeAt(0), b = b.charCodeAt(0), r = ""; 
     while(a <= b) 
         r += String.fromCharCode(a++); 
     return r 
}
charsBetween("a", "ö")

> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö"
```

See [character tables](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) for the reference.

For your validation, you probably want something like this instead:

```
 [^a-zA-Z0-9ÅÄÖåäö\s]
```

This matches ranges of latin letters and digits + individual characters from a list.

Comment: Due to the caret, the character class _doesn't_ match the specified characters.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of characters that we actually have no idea about, like Japanese or Russian and many more.
So to take them in account we need to use Unicode ranges rather than ASCII ranges in regular expressions.

I came with this regular expression that covers almost all written letters of the whole Unicode table, plus a bit more, like numbers, and few other characters for punctuation (Chinese punctuation is already included in Unicode ranges).
It is hard to cover everything and probably this ranges might include too many characters including "exotic" ones (symbols):

```
/^[\u0040-\u1FE0\u2C00-\uFFC00-9 ',.?!]+$/i
```

So I was using it this way to test (have to be not empty):

```
function validString(str) {
  return str && typeof(str) == 'string' && /^[\u0040-\u1FE0\u2C00-\uFFC00-9 ',.?!]+$/i.test(str);
}
```

Bear in mind that this is missing characters like:

```
:*()&#'\-:%
```

And many more others.